# What happens if a program is compiled while another instance is already running?

Tags: c++

`$ g++ program.cpp`

`$ ./a.out &`

(program.cpp is modified.)

`$ g++ program.cpp`

How can the running process still produce accurate results if the executable is overwritten?

Comment: It will always work with the build which you first associate it with and then unless you compile again it would consider your new change.So, it will produce the same result.And when you try running after overwritting,it will take the new one and consider it as a new build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really depends on how `ld` (invoked by `g++`) goes about creating
the new executable.  If it just does an `open` (with the proper flags
for creation if the file doesn't exist), then what happens to the
running process depends on paging, but there's a good chance of a crash.
If it does an `unlink` first, before creating the new file, the running
process will continue to use the old image, which will only be freed
when the process ends.

Traditionally, the original Unix linkers used the first strategy, which
has the advantage of keeping the access rights on an existing
executable.  This was, however, before the days of virtual memory, when
an executable was loaded in one shot, in the call to `exec`, and what
happened to the file afterwards was irrelevant.  Today, if I were
writing a linker, I'd use the second, but first read the mode of the
original file, and create the new file with the same mode.

You can easily see which strategy is being used by creating an
executable, then changing the mode, doing `ls -il` on it, then
recompiling, and doing `ls -il` again.  If the inode number has changed,
the linker is doing an `unlink` before opening the output.  And if the
mode has changed (back to whatever the default is in your environment),
the linker is failing to read the orginal mode before doing the
`unlink`.

In the case of g++ under Linux, both the inode number and the mode
change.  (I'd consider the fact that the mode changes a bug.)  IIRC, on
the other hand, `ld` under Solaris did not delete the file—I don't
recall doing the above test, but I do have vague memories of programs
crashing when we recompiled one of the DLL's they were using.

Finally, FWIW, why deleting the file doesn't crash the application:
files under Unix (represented by inodes) are reference counted, and are
deleted automatically when the reference count goes to 0.  (Very much
like `shared_ptr`.) There is a reference count for each directory entry
pointing to the file (each hard link), and for each open file descriptor
referring to the file.  "Deleting" a file under Unix doesn't actually
touch the file, it just removes the directory entry pointing to it
(which decrements the use count, which may result in the file being
deleted).  A loaded executable contains an open file descriptor for its
executable and all of the `.so`s it has loaded, which counts as a
reference to the file, so deleting the last directory entry pointing to
it will still leave the reference count greater than 0.

EDIT: I might add that unlinking will also break hard links (which will
remain pointing to the old version).  This is probably not an issue
today, since everyone only uses soft links (which are references to a
file name, and not to a file itself), but I can remember back in the
early days, before soft links existed, we took pains to avoid breaking
links: in the editor I worked on, we wrote the output to a totally new
file, then either moved that to the original file (if the inode count
was 1), or copied it (if the inode count was greater than 1; i.e. if
there were other hard links to the file we didn't know about).

Comment: Thanks! I was actually writing an answer to explain that with inodes Linux's behavior was slightly different, but your answer is much more detailed that what I could have achieved, by far!

Comment: About the Edit, `unlink` shouldn't break any other hard links to the file. That is why it is called `unlink` I believe, it removes the link from the given name to the inode. Other hard links should still have the reference and retain the inode...?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y It depends on what you understand the links to mean.  `unlink` leaves all other hard links pointing to the original inode.  If you unlink and then create a new file, however, the new file will have a new inode, and the old hard links will still point to the old file.  Which typically isn't what you want.

Answer (score 8):

Because the old file still exists. The directory entry will point to a new file, but the old file will exist as long as it remains open. Once closed, it will finally be deleted. That is, on Unix. On Windows you would likely not be able to do this since the file is open and can not be overwritten.

Comment: This depends on how `ld` creates its output file.  If it just does an `open`, the existing file will be truncated, which will probably cause the executable to crash.  (On the other hand, if the executable is completely paged in when this happens, or doesn't require a new page from the executable, it might continue to run, despite the fact that it's image on disk has disappeared.)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.

The earlier `./a.out` process maps the contents of the `a.out` into memory (in various sections, you can see them in `/proc/$PID/smaps`).

The later `g++ program.cpp` *unlinks* the existing `a.out` file and creates a new file with the same name.  The earlier file, which the earlier executable still has mapped into memory, is not modified.

Comment: This depends on the Unix (and the `ld`) being used.  Traditional implementations of `ld` do **not** unlink the existing output file, to avoid changing its permissions: if I've done `chmod 700 ./a.out` before invoking `g++`, I expect the `a.out` to have mode `-rwx------` after invoking `g++`, and if I've done `chmod 600 ./a.out`, I expect the link to fail, because I'm trying to modify a write protected file.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's a bit of history I didn't know!  At the very least, Linux prevents modifications to a file being executed (`open(O_WR)` will fail with `errno=ETXTBSY`), but the same might not apply to shared libraries.

Comment: The permissions are still an issue; if `ld` is going to remove the file and create a new one, it should read the old permissions first, and create the new one using them.  This issue with hard links may be becoming irrelevant; most people seem to use soft links exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix once the old file is closed it will be deleted whereas on Windows it will throw an error saying unable to copy the executable on the desired location